# Why am I getting the error " AttributeError: 'MySQLCursor' object has no attribute 'exceute' "?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, mysql-python, pythonanywhere

I am creating a CRUD based web app using Flask and Python.

Here is the link to it: https://zcds4327.pythonanywhere.com/

Here is the repository's link: https://github.com/OCTRACORE/cs_proj_pro_1

**Tree structure:**

```
.
├── Password_creator.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── Password_creator.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── exec_prog.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── global_data.cpython-38.pyc
│   └── table.cpython-38.pyc
├── exec_prog.py
├── global_data.py
├── passwd_file
├── requirements.txt
├── start.sh
├── static
│   ├── AddPasswdInp.css
│   ├── dispManipMenu.css
│   ├── favicon_io
│   │   ├── android-chrome-192x192.png
│   │   ├── apple-touch-icon.png
│   │   ├── favicon-32x32.png
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   └── site.webmanifest
│   ├── input.css
│   ├── show.css
│   └── showOutput.css
├── table.py
└── template
    ├── add.html
    ├── file-manip.html
    ├── input.html
    ├── modify.html
    ├── output_disp.html
    ├── semantic-error.html
    └── str_main.html
```

**Parent directory of the code:**`cs_proj_pro_1`

**Code snippet (from exec_prog.py)**

```
@app.route('/generate/file-manip',methods = ["GET","POST"]) # for saving the password(s)
def save_file():
  pass_output_lst = [] #for passwords
  desc_output_lst = [] #for descriptions of the password
  encrypted_pass_output_lst = [] #storing passwords after encryption
  encrypted_desc_output_lst = [] #storing descriptions of passwords after encryption
  UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.getcwd()
  app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
  if request.method == "POST": # checking if the request method is POST
      pass_file = request.files['passfile'] #requesting the name of the password saving file
      pass_file_Name = secure_filename(pass_file.filename) #storing the name of the password saving file
      desc_file = request.files['descfile'] #for the file storing descriptions of the file
      desc_file_Name =secure_filename(desc_file.filename)
      key = Fernet.generate_key() # generating a key
      key_init = Fernet(key)  # storing the key for encrypting purpose
      key_file = request.files['keyfile']  # requesting the key saving file
      key_file_name = secure_filename(key_file.filename) #storing the name of the key saving file
      file_lst = [pass_file_Name,desc_file_Name,key_file_name]

      for i in GlobalData.password:
       encrypted_pass_output_lst.append(key_init.encrypt(bytes(i.passwd,encoding="utf-8")))
       encrypted_desc_output_lst.append(key_init.encrypt(bytes(i.desc,encoding="utf-8")))
      with open(pass_file_Name,"wb+") as k:

       for i in encrypted_pass_output_lst:
         k.write(i)
         k.write(b'\n')

      with open(desc_file_Name,"wb+") as k:

       for i in encrypted_desc_output_lst:
         k.write(i)
         k.write(b'\n')
      with open(key_file_name,"wb+") as k:
        k.write(key)


  if GlobalData.password == []: # for showing the error when no password is created
    return render_template('semantic-error.html',message = "Illegal method. Can't save the file when no password is generated")
  else: #[pass_file_Name,desc_file_Name,key_file_name]

        zip_obj = zipfile.ZipFile('/home/ZCDS4327/proj/cs_proj_pro_1/zipfile.zip','w')#creating a zip file and storing it inside an object

        #SQL Execution(an SQL table stores number of password generated by the user along with it's date and time)
        getDate = datetime.datetime.now() #date and time of generating the passwords
        cursor = mydb.cursor()
        n_passwd = len(GlobalData.password) #number of passwords generated
        insert_query = "INSERT INTO password_table(n_passwd,c_date) VALUES(%s,%s)" %(n_passwd,getDate) #inserting the passwords inside the table password_site
        cursor.exceute(insert_query)
        mydb.commit()


        for i in file_lst:
            zip_obj.write(i,compress_type =zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) #inserting the required files inside the zip file
        zip_obj.close()
        zip_obj_name = zip_obj.filename
        for i in file_lst:
            os.remove(i) #removing the txt files
        del file_lst
        return send_file(zip_obj_name),os.remove('/home/ZCDS4327/proj/cs_proj_pro_1/zipfile.zip') #downloading the zipfile and deleting it from the working directory
```

**Working Directory:**

```
/home/ZCDS4327/proj/cs_proj_pro_1
```

**Environment used:** Python anywhere

The user gets the ability to store the passwords generated along with their corresponding descriptions inside two different text files by encrypting them. Also, another text file containing the key for encrypting is also given to the user. Then a zip file, containing the files get downloaded to the user's device.

During this process, an SQL query is executed where the number of passwords generated by the user is stored along with the date and timing of the task carried out.

The code snippet is for the SQL related task is mentioned there:

```
#SQL Execution(an SQL table stores number of password generated by the user along with it's date and time)
getDate = datetime.datetime.now() #date and time of generating the passwords
cursor = mydb.cursor()
n_passwd = len(GlobalData.password) #number of passwords generated
insert_query = "INSERT INTO password_table(n_passwd,c_date) VALUES(%s,%s)" %(n_passwd,getDate) #inserting the passwords inside the table password_site
cursor.exceute(insert_query)
mydb.commit()
```

But when I am carrying out the task for testing the process I am getting an *Internal server error*.

The error log shows the following error:

```
2020-10-16 12:48:44,016: Exception on /generate/file-manip [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ZCDS4327/proj/cs_proj_pro_1/exec_prog.py", line 149, in save_file
    cursor.exceute(insert_query)
AttributeError: 'MySQLCursor' object has no attribute 'exceute'
```

Even after trying to find this error by searching it on the internet, I have not found anything useful.

Therefore, I want to know what to do in order to resolve this error.

Comment: You are getting this error because `cursor.exceute()` is not a valid function. The function is `cursor.execute()`. Just a simple typo:)

Comment: I see. That was so ignorant of me.